# Keeping my personal feature branch up-to-date with the master branch of a project I 've forked

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I've forked a Github project (let's call it `ProjectA`) and then cloned my fork on my local machine. I then did some limited work on a feature branch of mine (which I've branched off my fork's master). This is very narrow feature work for my particular case and there is no point in trying to get the project's creator pull in my very modest contributions.

That was half a year ago.

I now just need to keep my feature branch up-to-date with any development that has since transpired in the `master` branch of the `ProjectA`.

At this point the `master` branch of my forked project is (according to **Github**)  "*172 commits behind ProjectA:master*".

Also my feature branch is "*1 commit ahead, 172 commits behind ProjectA:master*" (which I guess makes sense given the above).

Question is what's the cleanest way to do that given that I have no intention for my changes to enter into the code base of the original `ProjectA`.

Should I update my forked project's `master` to bring it up-to-date with the `master` of `ProjectA` and then re-base by feature branch on top of it? Something else? I would appreciate actual commands.

Answer (score 1):

According to Github, the best way to update your fork is to add the repository of `ProjectA` as upstream and fetch the changes from them. Merge the changes from the upstream (ProjectA) into your local forks `master` branch or whatever branch you like.

A step by step guid is given by Github: [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).